# Got error "missing separator" in make file

Tags: linux, makefile

I want to install linux-ftools from source. You can see the overview of linux-ftools in  this [link](https://code.google.com/p/linux-ftools/source/browse/install-sh). So I download the zip file and extract it. Then I enter the directory and type configure. Everything was good until I typed `make` and got this error:

> Makefile:16: *** missing separator.  Stop.

So i check Makefile and found this code in line 16:

```
@SET_MAKE@ #line 16


pkgdatadir = $(datadir)/@PACKAGE@ pkgincludedir =
$(includedir)/@PACKAGE@ pkglibdir = $(libdir)/@PACKAGE@ pkglibexecdir
= $(libexecdir)/@PACKAGE@ am__cd = CDPATH="$${ZSH_VERSION+.}$(PATH_SEPARATOR)" && cd install_sh_DATA =
$(install_sh) -c -m 644 install_sh_PROGRAM = $(install_sh) -c
install_sh_SCRIPT = $(install_sh) -c
```

What should I do ? I have searching a lot for fix this issue and still got no solutions.

Comment: `@SET_MAKE@` implies this is not a makefile, it's an autoconf template that should be transformed into a makefile by the configure script

Comment: There's something really weird going on.  The filename in the error is "Makefile".  The poster says he ran configure and didn't mention doing something like "copied Makefile.in to Makefile" (which would be wrong).  Yet clearly this makefile has not been properly processed by configure, which is hard to understand since the entire point of configure's complexity is to be maximally portable.  What is your operating system / distribution?

Comment: @MadScientist i use ubuntu 14.04 LTS.